# Cannot authorize me using OAuth 1.0a, failing when requesting an accesToken

Tags: oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to authorize me on service using OAuth 1.0a. I can do the `requestToken` and `authorize` steps but when I call the `accessToken` URL I get a *401 Unauthorized* response back with the following message:
`OAuth Verification Failed: Can't exchange request token "THE_TOKEN" for access token. No such token or not authorized%`

I have masked the credentials and URLs.

Request token URL: https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/requestToken
Authorize token URL: https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/authorize
Access token URL: https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/accessToken

The credentials I have gotten from the service is the following:
**consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY** 
**consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET**

## STEP 1 - request a temporary token

```
curl -v -X GET --url "https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/requestToken?oauth_version=1.0& \
oauth_timestamp=1516721112& \
oauth_nonce=25794& \
oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT& \
oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY& \
oauth_signature=CONSUMER_SECRET%26"
```

The service then responds with:

`oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=THE_TOKEN&oauth_token_secret=THE_TOKEN_SECRET&xoauth_token_ttl=3600`

## STEP 2 - authorize me with the temporary token and get a verifier

I then enter this into my browser:

https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=THE_TOKEN

...and it prompts me to log in to the service. When I press the authorize button after logging in I am forwarded to this URL:

https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/authorize?yes=1&oauthVerifier=123456789&oauth_token=THE_TOKEN

## STEP 3 - request access token

Finally, I make a request to `https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/accessToken` by adding the `oauth_verifier` and the token secret to the `oauth_signature`:

```
curl -v -X GET --url "https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/accessToken?oauth_version=1.0& \ 
oauth_timestamp=1516730938& \
oauth_nonce=30888& \
oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT& \
oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY& \
oauth_signature=CONSUMER_SECRET%26THE_TOKEN_SECRET& \
oauth_token=THE_TOKEN& \
oauth_verifier=123456789"
```

But the service responds with: 
`OAuth Verification Failed: Can't exchange request token "THE_TOKEN" for access token. No such token or not authorized%`

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

According to [rfc5849 3.2 Verifying Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.2)

> The server SHOULD return a 401 (Unauthorized) status
> code when receiving a request with invalid **client credentials**, an
> **invalid or expired token**, an **invalid signature**, or an **invalid or used
> nonce**.

I am not sure the value `xoauth_token_ttl=3600` from the step 1 is minutes or seconds. If it is seconds, the first request at 1516721112 and the access token request at 1516730938 has expired. (1516730938 - 1516721112 = 9826)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forcing a GET request in your cURL request. Try a POST request like below:

```
curl -v -X POST --url "https://url-to-the-service.com/oauth/accessToken?
oauth_version=1.0& \ 
oauth_timestamp=1516730938& \
oauth_nonce=30888& \
oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT& \
oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY& \
oauth_signature=CONSUMER_SECRET%26THE_TOKEN_SECRET& \
oauth_token=THE_TOKEN& \
oauth_verifier=123456789"
```

Refer to the [OAuth1 documentation](https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Auth-Flow.html). Quoting here for reference:

> **Token Exchange**
>
> The final step in authorization is to exchange the temporary
>   credentials (request token) for long-lived credentials (also known as
>   an Access Token). This request also destroys the temporary
>   credentials.
>
> **The temporary credentials are converted to long-lived credentials by
>   sending a POST request to the token request endpoint** (typically
>   /oauth1/access). This request must be signed by the temporary
>   credentials, and must include the oauth_verifier token from the
>   authorization step.